# Cassandra 3.11 commit logs nightmare

Tags: cassandra

Clean installs of Cassandra 3.11 nodes are working fine for me for a few days, and then ‘nodetool flush’ and ‘nodetool compact’ are starting to throw exceptions. After this, restarts after a ‘nodetool drain’, fail. forcing deletion of commitlogs. Is this a problem with 3.11 in general? If What version do we need to downgrade to, to resolve this?

(I recognise that the causes might not be related to 3.11, ie perhaps or something about the key space I have, or perhaps an issue with Ubuntu 16? But I am just asking about 3.11 specifically and if it has some sort of known flaw threat I can’t see in JIRA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Cassandra 3.11.x series that means `nodetool flush` and `nodetool compact` fail when using a 32 bit install of Java. Switching to 64 bit version solves the problem.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13897